# Is this a foolproof way to check whether two columns are equal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm curious about the answer to this as I'm trying to debug a deeper issue. Are there any data types for which the check

```
    s.[SomeColumn] != t.[SomeColumn] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2
        OR (s.[SomeColumn] IS NULL AND t.[SomeColumn] IS NOT NULL)
        OR (s.[SomeColumn] IS NOT NULL AND t.[SomeColumn] IS NULL)
```

, where `SomeColumn` is the same type on tables `s` and `t`, will give me any false negatives?

Comment: i don't envisage an issue provided that those columns are of the same data type.. collation is done over the server there's no point collating again unless for a valid reason like ALL CAPS and other string culture issues. You should only deal with NULLS... ie. ISNULL(column1,'')  <> ''

Comment: `COLLATE` only works on strings, so this won't work on most types.  I haven't used it on other data types.  If it forces a conversion to a string, then it could possibly mess up the comparison.

Comment: Collation seems like overkill unless you are specifically working with differently collated environments

Comment: The only data type I can think of that this would get a little bit wonky with would be sql_variant?

Comment: The trailing spaces can also cause problems.

Comment: So what is the problem you want to debug?

Comment: You will find that trying to compare floating point numbers **exactly** is always a problem - in every language. 14.99997 and 15.000001 are often "the same" though the actual bits are different.